# subtract a small matrix from a large matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization

I have two matrices, one with say 1000 rows and the other with a million rows (and the same number of columns), `M_small` and `M_large`.

I would like to find, for the small matrix, if there are rows in `M_large` for which the difference between `M_large` and `M_small` are close to zero (less than 0.5).

For example:

```
M_small = structure(c(10, 1, 7, 11, 2, 8, 12, 3, 9, 13, 4, 10, 14, 5, 11
), .Dim = c(3L, 5L))

M_large = structure(c(10.1, 0.9, 300, 100, 65, 1.2, 15, 200, 400, 11.01, 
8.11, 2.11, 16, 3.05, 500, 300, 9.12, 33, 13.2, 40, 600, 400, 
77, 45, 20, 55, 700, 1000, 88, 56), .Dim = 6:5)
```

For each row of `M_small`, I would like to find the rows and columns of `M_large` which are close to `M_small`. So e.g:

```
M_large - M_small[1,]
```

reveals that the first row of `M_small` is close to `M_large` in columns `1` and `4` (the difference is `0.1` and `0.2`, respectively).

How can I achieve this VERY efficiently?

Comment: Is the 0.5 difference sum of the differences (0.1 + 0.2) or individual one ? what would your expected output look like for given example?

Comment: How do you want the output? Maybe something like `lapply(seq(nrow(M_small)), function(i) which(abs(M_large - M_small[i,]) <= 0.5, arr.ind = TRUE))`?

Comment: This is a good start, problem is lapply is the same as using a loop - very inefficient for large matrices

Comment: Are you trying to subtract each row in `M_small` from all rows in `M_large`? if that's the case then this  `t(t(M_large) - M_small[1, ])` is what you want, because adding a vector to a matrix happens by column. Try running `M_large[2, ] - M_small[1,]` and compare it with the second row of `M_large - M_small[1,]`